# IntelliJ cannot prepare workspace

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ubuntu-20.04

from  yesterday,when i've tried to install flutter sdk on my ubuntu, My IntelliJ cannot prepare a workspace when I'm trying to create (any kind of Java) new projects, anymore.My OS is ubuntu20.4. what should i do?

Comment: Do you get any error/warning? Have you checked idea.log ("Help | Show log in...")?

Comment: @y.bedrov
For me, This error was caused by memory overflow. I went to the main jetbrain directory and cleared the space occupied by the previous versions I had installed.